# Using decltype in std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

Consider these three statements:

```
std::map<int, std::string> foo;
std::map<int, std::string>::value_type;
decltype(foo)::value_type;
```

Why isn't the last one legal? I thought that `decltype(foo)` would be an operator yielding the map type `std::map<int, std::string>` from which I could extract the `value_type`.

I'm using MSVC2012.

Comment: You need to add a variable name, or some sort of initialisation: [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d72e22014c54473e).

Comment: I don't think so. The second statement compiles correctly.

Comment: You're right. Your code should actually just compile as-is. I think that this is a bug in your compiler.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with VS2012. It doesn't implement C++11 fully. I think VS2013 fixes this, though I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC and Clang allow this syntax, your compiler is failing at properly implementing C++11.

You can do this, though:

```
std::map<int, std::string> foo;
std::map<int, std::string>::value_type;
using some_type = decltype(foo);
some_type::value_type;
```

Comment: Thanks. Good to know its a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1):

Its valid, you have other errors, you must give a name to your variable:

```
std::map<int, std::string> foo;
std::map<int, std::string>::value_type nn_var;
decltype(foo)::value_type nn2_var;
typedef decltype(foo)::value_type value_type;
```

Comment: Not true, at least for in MSVC2012: `decltype(foo)::value_type t;` still gives me a compile error (the global scope has no ::value_type)

Comment: I dont have MSVS2012 but it works with g++4.8: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5195e8223a4fc791 and clang: http://rextester.com/PPN15989

Comment: ok, ignore this rise4fun sample - it gives 'File compiled with no errors!' even with obviously inserted errors!

Comment: @SlodgeMonster Sadly Visual Studio 2013 also suffers from this problem.

Comment: @JonathanMee under VS2013 update 4 it does compile for me, but intellisence marks those lines as red

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
std::remove_reference<decltype(foo)>::type::value_type
```